# Why do raster band values have different values than raster statistics in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am working on a raster file (1 Band).

According to the raster metadata, my minimum value is 0 and maximum is 7458. This seems to be confirmed by the Style options that return some category values in the value range mentioned above. In addition, these numbers make total sense with the nature of my data.

However, when I use the "Identify Features" tool, I get some values completely out of the range (these values look like this one generally: 4.5761380462188e-315).

I don't understand why and it's a problem because I would like sometimes to get the value of a single pixel. Do you have an idea why I have this discrepancy between the Identify Feature tool and the raster statistics?

I use QGIS 2.2.0-Valmiera on Windows 7.

Comment: 4.5761380462188e-315 is not out of your data range. It is a very small postive number, which is between 0 and 7458.

Comment: Correct. I was not clear. The problem is that I know that pixel has a value around 2500. It is confirmed by the style I applied. Indeed, Qgis applies to that pixel the color I chose for the value between 2400 and 2600.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that 4.5761380462188e-315 is intended as a null / no data value, so when you look at the raw data (e.g. using the Identify Features tool) you will see these values (all the nulls should have the same values).  On the other hand the raster metadata is ignoring these null values, because they aren't really values...

Comment: Yes, but all the pixels seems to have that sort of very small value when I use the "Identify Features" tool.